# Не получается выровнять текст по вертикали

Tags: css

```css
    .category {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        background: rgb(26, 26, 26);
        margin: 2px;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }
```

```html
<p class="category" style="background: #2271b1 !important;" onclick="loadCId(86)">Прав. Повар</p>
<p class="category" style="" onclick="loadCId(87)">БЛА ЕДА</p></div>

<div style="z-index: 90; position: fixed; top:175px; right: 0; background: #f3f3f3; border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px;">
<p class="product2">Итого<br>1240 руб</p>
<p class="product2" onclick="loadpage('content/plugins/Ekassir/finOrder.php')">Продолжить</p>
<p class="product2" onclick="">Ожидание 60мин</p>
<p class="product2" onclick="claerCart()">Аннулировать заказ</p></div>
```

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простое решение:

(добавил line-height)

```css
    .category {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 120px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        background: rgb(26, 26, 26);
        margin: 2px;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }
```

```html
<p class="category" style="background: #2271b1 !important;" onclick="loadCId(86)">Прав. Повар</p>
<p class="category" style="" onclick="loadCId(87)">БЛА ЕДА</p></div>
```

Чуть более сложное решение (через flexbox и margin)

```css
.category {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    background: rgb(26, 26, 26);
}

.category .content {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="category" style="background: #2271b1 !important;" onclick="loadCId(86)">
  <p class="content">Прав. Повар</p>
</div>

<div class="category" style="" onclick="loadCId(87)">
  <p class="content">БЛА ЕДА</p>
</div>
```

Comment: По правой стороне скрина многострочные блоки, там так не сработает. А верстка у них такая же.

Comment: В вашем примере этих блоков нет) Уверены что не сработает? Могу дать более общее решение

Comment: Добавил код правого блока. Разница в классах только background.

Comment: @kir Так у вас класс у боковых блоков другой)

Comment: Не в этом дело, правку то я и в тот класс тоже ввел) Вот только наполнение этих блоков берется из базы, а там и 4-х строчные, иногда, получаются блоки. А line-height это как раз таки высота строки т.е. вместо того, чтоб выровнять по вертикали, мы просто растянули строки)

Comment: Не сработало...

Comment: @kir Так бы и сказали, что у вас строки многострочные... Тогда лучше будет второй вариант

Comment: Все работает, благодарю